# What node type (Primary, Core, or Task) I am connected to in Amazon EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a script as a bootstrap action on all the EMR nodes (Primary, Core or Task nodes). This script will be publishing metrics to AWS CloudWatch. When publishing metrics to AWS CloudWatch, I would like to also send the information about which node type this metric came from. Is/are there any command/s that I can add in the shell script that would give me information on which node type I am running that command on?

I tried running this command, but that does not contain any EMR information as it's related to only EC2 metadata info:

```
curl -s  http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

Another option is to fetch tags from the instance ID I get from the above EC2 metadata information as it has a tag that tells which node type it is. But, that would be an additional cost for getting tag information as I am planning to run this script as a scheduler every 5 minute.

Are there any other ways I can get this information on an EMR instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMR maintains information about the cluster (and instance) in the `/emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow-state.txt` file. There's a lot of info in there, but specifically there's a field called `instanceRole` that will tell you what type of instance your on.

- For primary nodes, the value will be `master`
- Core nodes, `core`
- Task nodes, `task`

You can get the value with a couple shell commands:

```
grep instanceRole /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow-state.txt | awk '{gsub(/"/, ""); print $2}'
```

*Note: The file is owned by the `hadoop` user so you need to be either `hadoop` or `root` to execute the above command.*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know where EMR instances stores this information. Thank you!